# How to import gql to create typedefs in apollo server v4?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

In the version 3 of apollo server, we could use `import {gql} from "apollo-server-express"` to create typedefs and schemas. But in v4 of apollo server, `apollo-server-express and apollo-server-core`  are depreciated and will be removed. So, instead of  importing `gql`  from `apollo-server-express`, how can we import `gql`

I tried import `gql` from new `@apollo/server` and it is not working either.

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/server";
const typeDefs = gql``;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Apollo v4 you should now import `qgl` from the [graphql-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag) package.

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
```